# check which checkbox is checked in panel

Tags: .net, visual-c++, checkbox, c++-cli, panel

can someone please help me with the following problem. 
When I push the button I need to check which checkbox are checked in the panel.
By default all checkboxes are checked. The idea is to have a vector that I store order number of the checkbox that is checked.
Code for dinamic input checkbox in panel is:

```
for each (FileInfo^ f in info->GetFiles())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < validExtensions->Length; i++)
    {
        if (f->Extension->ToString()->ToLower() == validExtensions[i]->ToLower())
        {
            PictureBox^ pb = gcnew PictureBox();
            CheckBox^ cb = gcnew CheckBox();

            pb->Name = "ImagePB" + countPB;
            cb->Name = "CheckBox" + countCB;

            pb->Cursor = Cursors::Hand;

            pb->Parent = panel1;                            
            pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size(130, 130);
            cb->Parent = panel1;

            pb->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::StretchImage;

            pb->Location = Point(positionX + 10, positionY);
            cb->Location = Point(positionX + 70, positionY + 130);

            pb->Image = Image::FromFile(f->FullName);

            pb->Image->Tag = f->FullName;

            pb->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Forma1::pb_Click);

            positionX += 141;
            if (positionX >= 770)
            {
                positionY += 154;
                positionX = 0;
            }

            countPB += 1;
            countCB += 1;

            cb->Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your question, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish and what problems you are having. Please be more specific.

Comment: I have a panel in c++ Form Aplication, in that panel I dinamicli add pictureBox and checkBox for each image in directory. User can check or uncheck checkBox below every picture. When i press button on form i need to send only those picture that have checked checkedbox below. So that in some way I have to find out what is checked.

Comment: @DenisŠtajduhar Well, checkboxes have a `Checked` property IIRC?

Comment: I tried this way:
for each (Control c in panel1->Controls)
{ CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
   if (cb->Checked = true) ..........


But c++ does not support AS keyword..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear how everything is structured, so this could be off, but you could maintain a dynamic list of all the checkboxes when you create/delete them. Then iterate over them when needed.

```
List<CheckBox^>^ checkboxes = gcnew List<Checkbox^>();

...
checkboxes->Add(gcnew CheckBox());

...

for each (Checkbox^ checkbox in checkboxes)
{
    if (checbox->Checked)
        DoSomething();
}
```